# Getting the LastWriteTime attribute from a binary resource

Tags: c#

I wanted to ask if it's possible to retrieve GetLastWriteTime info from a binary resource that's in my project

My attempts on doing it so far: (that's not really too much but I had no idea)

```
using System;
using System.IO;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var resource = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("test") as byte[];

            if (resource == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"null"); // this is never actually printed, just in case
            }
            else
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(File.GetLastWriteTime(resource));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider shiping the resources as just plain files with your application. Then you can just easily do the following, demonstrated by this example

```
        // For file Foo.bar that is in the same directory as your application.
        DateTime lastWriteTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Foo.bar"));
        Console.WriteLine(lastWriteTime.ToString("yy-MM-dd"));
```

Example output would be:

```
        01-02-03
```